# How to add numbers together using and If statement?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to make a program in android studio that when sellected a higher education it automatically adds 200$ to the pay that was previously entered. But instead of getting 500+200=700, I get 500200. I ran trough the code numerous times and just can't seem to find the error. I'm still new on Java. This is the second window that appears when submitting the information, It shows all the info entered in the first window, but for some reason it can't 200 to the entered pay

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rezultatas);

    Intent duom = getIntent();
    String pavarde = duom.getStringExtra("pavarde");
    String issilavinimas = duom.getStringExtra("issilavinimas");
    int pay = duom.getIntExtra("atlyginimas", 0);
    String laikas = duom.getStringExtra("laikas");

    TextView rez = findViewById(R.id.rezultatas);
    rez.setText("Pavardė: "+pavarde+"\n");
    rez.append("Išsilavinimas: "+issilavinimas+"\n");
    if(issilavinimas.equals("Aukštasis")){
        rez.append("Gaunamas atlyginimas: " +pay+ 200 + "\n");
    } else{
        rez.append("Gaunamas atlyginimas: "+pay+  "\n");
    }
    rez.append("Keliasi: "+laikas+"\n");

}
```

This is the first window where all the information is entered:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void saugoti(View v){
    EditText txt = findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    String pavarde = txt.getText().toString();

    Spinner issilavinimas = findViewById(R.id.issilavinimas);
    String issilav = issilavinimas.getSelectedItem().toString();

    EditText atl = findViewById(R.id.pay);
    int pay = Integer.parseInt(atl.getText().toString());

    TextView txt2 = findViewById(R.id.time);
    String laikas = txt2.getText().toString();

    Intent duom = new Intent(this, rezultatas.class);
    duom.putExtra("pavarde", pavarde);
    duom.putExtra("issilavinimas", issilav);
    duom.putExtra("laikas", laikas);
    duom.putExtra("atlyginimas", pay);

    startActivity(duom);
}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Comment: Surround `pay+ 200` with parentheses; i.e., `(pay + 200)`.

Comment: Oh I had no clue that parentheses were that important. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rezultatas);

    Intent duom = getIntent();
    String pavarde = duom.getStringExtra("pavarde");
    String issilavinimas = duom.getStringExtra("issilavinimas");
    int pay = duom.getIntExtra("atlyginimas", 0);
    int total=pay+ 200;
    String laikas = duom.getStringExtra("laikas");

    TextView rez = findViewById(R.id.rezultatas);
    rez.setText("Pavardė: "+pavarde+"\n");
    rez.append("Išsilavinimas: "+issilavinimas+"\n");
    if(issilavinimas.equals("Aukštasis")){
        rez.append("Gaunamas atlyginimas: " + total + "\n");
    } else{
        rez.append("Gaunamas atlyginimas: "+pay+  "\n");
    }
    rez.append("Keliasi: "+laikas+"\n");

}
```

when you `+` with `String` concatination is actually working there instead of addition